# wpf databinding of a deep property with a condition

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to show a property in a listview. My problem is that the data I want to show is much deeper then my ItemSource and it should only show only property with a specific value.

Here is a example:

```
public class Item
{
    private string id;
    private List<Tags> tags;

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }

        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Tags> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return tags;
        }

        set
        {
            tags = value;
        }
    }
public class Tags
{
    private string id;
    private Data d;

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }

        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    public Data D
    {
        get
        {
            return d;
        }

        set
        {
            d = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Data(){public string Text{set;get;}
```

And now i want to try to make something like this

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView"ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Tags.Data.Text}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

But now I want it to show only one Tags with a specific Id and not all Tags.
And Items is a ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm proposing 2 solutions for you.

1) see if this works:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tags.Data.Text}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If this doesn't work, let's refactor you code and make use of WPF capabilities...

2) alternative solution

Set in your ViewModel a property like:

```
public Tag SelectedTag 
{
  get {...}; 
  set 
    {  
        _selectedTag = value ;
        SelectedData = value!=null?_selectedTag.Data:null;
        //call notifypropertychanged here...    
    }
}; 

public Data SelectedData {get {...}; set {....}};
```

So in you ListView, make a binding like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
       SelectedItem={Binding SelectedTag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger="ProperyChanged">
   <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedData.Text,ElementName="YourWindowName"}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I dont think the first one will help^^, but the 2nd solutions looks like a viable way. I will give it after school a try.